# i want search in tree panel in sencha Classic (EXT JS).

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

i want search in tree panel in sencha Classic (EXT JS) like the search plugin of grid panel. i didn't find the plugin in the documentation of sencha.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a plugin. All you need to do is that a tree uses a tree store. Now in a tree store you have some more specialized methods available.

`treeStore.findNode`

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.TreeStore.html#method-findNode

**Docs:**
"Finds the first matching node in the tree by a specific field value regardless of visibility due to collapsed states; all nodes present in the tree structure are searched."
Now having the method doing the search just add a field then add an event listener on change on that field and perform the search.